# How cast a STRING to TEXT in Hive

Tags: hive

I'm using a custom-UDF which is expecting the type org.apache.hadoop.io.Text as an argument.  But the UDF fails because I'm passing in a string. What's the best way to cast my string into text in Hive?

eg

```
SELECT custom_udf(CAST str AS TEXT)) FROM my_table
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if this workaround works:

```
SELECT custom_udf(concat('', str)) FROM my_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

I though Hive String (column) and Hive Text (UDF param) are compatible to each other but i was wrong with my test. You would need to make evaluate method accept a generic (Object) type to achieve the same. concat function will result to String only thus it may not fulfill your need.